# Hamburger menu disappeared

Tags: codenameone, hamburger-menu

I have found that my hamburger menu in simulator and a on an ios device was "missing" - debugging the code on simulator the methods were being called but nothing displayed on screen.

Building against an earlier version of cn1 resolved the problem... so, has a bug been introduced in the latest code or something that changes how the hamburger menu (SideMenu) is used?

Answer (score 1):

The defaults icons have been replaced with the google material design font icons, see the [font image blog post](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/material-icons-background-music-geofencing-gradle.html)

It is very much likely your menu icon color is blended with your title, try to give a foreground color to the "MenuButton" uiid in your theme